# Getting arguments of any LaTeX command

Tags: latex-misc, latex-base, arguments

I do not like **R** and **LaTeX**. I simply love them. In **R**, I can get the arguments of any function using **args(function_name)** on command line. I wonder if we can get the list of all possible arguments of any **LaTeX** command. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not really. If you try `\show\section`, you'll find it actually has *no* argument.

Comment: @egreg Technically, that is the answer. It just probably isn't the one the OP wants.

Comment: You are probably looking the [LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

TeX has about three hundred primitive commands, but just a few of them are ever directly used in a LaTeX document. There is *no* method available for showing their arguments and it would be rather useless anyway, for the above mentioned reason: you don't use them, it's *macros* that do.

To add a layer of complication, TeX macros don't really allow for optional arguments or *-variants: this is obtained by clever use of macros.

If you do something like

```
\def\foo#1{foo is #1}
```

then you can type in your document

```
\show\foo
```

which would stop the run of TeX and display

```
> \foo=macro:
#1->foo is #1.
```

but that's all you can get. More complicated commands such as `\section` will display even more mysterious information:

```
\section=\long macro:
->\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }.
```

which means that `\section` has no argument whatsoever; what comes after `\section` in your typescript will be handed as an argument to `\@startsection`. Doing `\show\@startsection` will show a big amount of data much more mysterious than the above.

Moreover, `\section` is a command defined by the document class. Different classes may allow for different sets of arguments. The synopsis for `\section` (from a user's perspective) could be

```
\section*[<header and toc title>]{<title>}
```

with the explanation that when `*` is found, the optional argument is not allowed. However, this is true for `article` and other classes, but `memoir` allows for a different syntax

```
\section*[<header title>][<toc title>]{<title>}
```

(if a single optional argument is used, the result would be the same as for `article`).

What you can do is to rely upon *manuals*. For instance, the [LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.pdf) describes the most important commands in the LaTeX kernel and in the standard `article`, `report` and `book` classes.

For other commands defined by additional packages, you should consult the respective documentation.

Programming languages such as R or Pari-GP can and do show the syntax for each command, maybe also telling the user what kind of argument is expected. There *might* be a way for doing something similar for LaTeX commands, but it would add a big burden on the package author (and no package provides such a thing except in documentation).